# How to Wrap dynamic string variables in double quoutes

Tags: json

I have static body which works great. But how I can wrap the same dynamic strings with double quotes - >""

Static Body

```
     var body = @"{" + "\n" +
        @"  ""profile"": {" + "\n" +
        @"    ""firstName"": ""Isaac1""," + "\n" +
        @"    ""lastName"": ""Brock1""," + "\n" +
        @"    ""email"": ""isaac1.brock@example.com""," + "\n" +
        @"    ""login"": ""isaac1.brock@example.com""," + "\n" +
        @"    ""mobilePhone"": ""555-415-1337""" + "\n" +
        @"  }" + "\n" +
        @"}";
```

Dyanmic Content (FirstName, LastName, Email, MobilePhone should all be wrapped with "")

```
var body1 = @"{" + "\n" +
                        @"  ""profile"": {" + "\n" +
                        @"    ""firstName"": "+ firstName + "," + "\n" +
                        @"    ""lastName"": "+lastName+"," + "\n" +
                        @"    ""email"": "+email+"," + "\n" +
                        @"    ""login"": "+email+"," + "\n" +
                        @"    ""mobilePhone"": "+mobilePhone+"" + "\n" +
                        @"  }" + "\n" +
                        @"}";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap a variable using string escape syntax " \ ""

```
var body1 = @"{" + "\n" +
                        @"  ""profile"": {" + "\n" +
                        @"    ""firstName"": " + "\"" + firstName + "\"" + "," + "\n" +
                        @"    ""lastName"": " + "\"" + lastName + "\"" + "," + "\n" +
                        //..... 
                        @"  }" + "\n" +
                        @"}";
```

but IMHO it is more safe to create a json object and after this to serialize it to a json string , using Newtonsoft.Json for example

```
var body = new JObject {
      ["profile"]=new JObject {
      ["firstName"] = firstName,
      ["lastName"] = lastName
      //...
    }
    }.ToString();
```

or you can replace JObject with an anonymos class and serialize after creaing.

```
var body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
    {
        profile = new
        {
            firstName = firstName,
            lastName = lastName
            //...
        }
    }, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Comment: Thank you so much works Amazing.

Comment: Hello @Serge Thanks for sharing. Is it possible to share a sample code of " anonymos class and serialize after creaing."

Comment: Any idea how to create a JObject for this `var body = @"{" + "\n" +
@"  ""profile"": {" + "\n" +
@"    ""firstName"": ""Isaac""," + "\n" +
@"    ""lastName"": ""Brock""," + "\n" +
@"    ""email"": ""isaac.brock@example.com""," + "\n" +
@"    ""login"": ""isaac.brock@example.com""," + "\n" +
@"    ""mobilePhone"": ""555-415-1337""" + "\n" +
@"  }," + "\n" +
@"  ""groupIds"": [" + "\n" +
@"    ""00g1emaKYZTWRYYRRTSK""," + "\n" +
@"    ""00garwpuyxHaWOkdV0g4""" + "\n" +
@"  ]" + "\n" +
@"}";`

Comment: basically adding this block ` "groupIds": [
    "00g1emaKYZTWRYYRRTSK",
    "00garwpuyxHaWOkdV0g4"
  ]`

Comment: @sgl If you need just JObject you can parse your json -  JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(body);

Comment: But I dont have a json to create jobject. I want to create from dynamic data like this `            var body = new JObject
            {
                ["profile"] = new JObject
                {
                    ["firstName"] = firstName,
                    ["lastName"] = lastName,
                    ["email"] = email,
                    ["login"] = email,
                    ["mobilePhone"] = mobilePhone
                },
                ["groupIds"] = new JObject
                { 
                   
                }

            }.ToString();`

Comment: any idea how to pass groupids

Comment: @sql Use JArray to create an array -  ["groupIds"] = new JArray("00g1emaKYZTWRYYRRTSK","00garwpuyxHaWOkdV0g4")